# makeStyles does not respond to dynamic CSS variables

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  paper: {
    color: "var(--text-color) !important",
  },
})
```

The CSS variable `var(--text-color)` changes throughout the APP based on a toggle. But the component that uses this `useStyles` does not change with it.

What is wrong here?

EDITED:

This fixed it:

```
          <Autocomplete disablePortal />
```

Now, can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it:

```
          <Autocomplete disablePortal />
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30755751)

Comment: actually, that is the complete solution. Setting `disablePortal` is it

Comment: If you want people to answer with why this happens, it would probably be better to move this line to the question, so the question itself can be "here's the problem, here's what fixed it, can the answers explain what's happening and why?"